# Simulation of custom probability distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to simulate the following distribution:

```
 a   |  0   |  1   |  7   |  11  |  13 
-----------------------------------------
p(a) | 0.34 | 0.02 | 0.24 | 0.29 | 0.11
```

I already simulated a similar problem: four type of balls with chances of 0.3, 0.1, 0.4 and 0.2. I created a vector `F = [0 0.3 0.4 0.8 1]` and used repmat to grow it by 1000 rows. Then I compared it with a columnvector of 1000 random numbers grown with 5 columns using the same `repmat` approach. I compared those two, calculated the sumvector of the matrix, and calculated the difference to get the frequences (e.g. `[301 117 386 196]`). .

But with the current distribution I don't know how to create the initial matrix `F` and whether I can use the same approach I used before at all.

I need the answer to be "vectorised", so no (`for`, `while` or `if`) loops.

[This question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507795/simulation-of-custom-distribution-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

What if you create the following arrays:

```
largeNumber = 1000000;
a=repmat( [0], 1, largeNumber*0.34 );
b=repmat( [1], 1, largeNumber*0.02 );
% ...
e=repmat( [13], 1, largeNumber*0.11 );
```

Then you concatenate all of these arrays (to get a single array where your entries are represented with their corresponding probabilities), shuffle them, and extract the first `N` elements to get an `N`-dimensional vector drawn from your distribution.

EDIT: of course [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/507807/81933) answer is the way to go.